# Ruby (server) - Java (client) connection error

Tags: java, ruby, json, sockets

(Running Server and Client on same machine, hence localhost is used in client code)
Basically i have what this program does is send a string to the client side that he will later convert to json. but the converting on the client part is not my error. its that on the client side (java) after i successfully connect to my server (ruby) when i proceed the ObjectInputStreams (in) and ObjectOuputStreams(out) from my request socket....out =  requestSocket.getOutputStream() works fine but in = requesSocket.getInputStream() gives me an IOException.. ive tried everything but am yet unable to fix this any help is appreciated. PD: this is not a HW, just me playing around wanting to learn interaction between different languages.

this is the error on the client side:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
```

RUBY CODE (Server)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'socket'
require 'json'

jsonString = '{"test":23, "prueba":1234}'
serverB = TCPServer.new(2000) 

loop{#server runs forever
Thread.start(serverB.accept) do |client|
    client.write(jsonString)
    client.close    #disconnect from the client
end

}
```

JAVA CODE (Client) --->UPDATED

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import org.json.simple.*;
public class json 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Socket requestSocket;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;   
    try {
        //creating a socket to connect to the server
        requestSocket = new Socket("localhost",2000);
        //Get input and output streams
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();

                    //THIS WORKS NOW
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestSocket.getInputStream()));

                    //THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS NOW
        String jsonString = in.readLine();
        String msg = JSONValue.toJSONString(jsonString);

        //Convert string to JSON format and print something
        Object obj = JSONValue.parse(msg);
        JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)obj;
        System.out.print(jobj.get("test"));

        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            requestSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I don't know Java that well, but to me it seems you are using Java `ObjectStream` primitives to read plain strings from the socket. I would think a Java `ObjectStream` can only communicate with another `ObjectStream`. I.e. you can only pass Java objects inside such a stream. A plain Ruby string is not a Java object so that code will never interoperate like that. You need to read plain strings on the Java side too, not `ObjectStream` stuff.

Comment: Basically call just `requestSocket.read()` on the Java side (I'm guessing since I'm no Java guru). Skip all that `Stream` stuff away.

Comment: again, reading is not the problem for me in this case because i havent got pass the requestSocket.getInputStream() part...

Comment: Hmm..well if you look at the call stack the `ObjectStream` is trying to read from the socket (`readStreamHeader`). You don't know how many bytes it is trying to read in order to establish the stream type. I'm still going to be stubborn and say it's failing because it's expecting an `ObjectStream` and it's getting essentially garbage. If you want to confirm your Ruby code is working then `telnet localhost 2000` if you're on a Unix box to test your Ruby code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and you still have the problem that you are running an `ObjectOutputStream`. Comment out those two lines (the ones ending in `out.flush()`).

Also now you are calling `readLine()`, so that means `BufferedReader` is expecting a line. A line is something ending with `"\r\n"`.

So the fix is to add that to the Ruby code:

```
Thread.start(serverB.accept) do |client|
  client.write(jsonString)
  client.write("\r\n")
  client.close
end
```

Running it like that it works for me (Linux Ubuntu).

Comment: yea i got to that conclusion a couple of hours ago, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ObjectInputStream to read a JSON string, you must read it as a string and then use the json package to convert it to an object.

ObjectInputStream is for reading binary-serialized java objects, it has nothing to do with json.

Comment: i never mentioned the problem was with json, again my problem is when i try to get the inpustream from the requestSocket, either way i do it it still doesnt work.

Comment: UPDATE: i got the inputstream working now: used this instead: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestSocket.getInputStream()));

but when I read the line : String jsonString = in.readLine();
the programs just gives me an error: